# How to improve the precision of the result due to the lack of precision in C++ division

Tags: c++, precision

I am working on the leibniz question as indicated https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/leibniz here.
 which computes 1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9+... Each element in the sequence can be defined as a(i)=(-1)^i/(2*i+1) start i from 0.

The question requires that to add from the first term to the nth term and output the result. My program passes the basic test cases. But it fails in other cases.

I guess my program fault is due to the precision when the number is large enough.

Can anybody provide a way to improve the precision of the result?

```
double leibnitz(int n) {
    double res = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res += 1.0 / (2 * i - 1) * (i % 2 == 1 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Whats the fault? You haven't mentioned what exactly goes wrong, or what kind of input triggers such wrong behavior.

Comment: Ace.  What is the question?

Comment: this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637621/c-calculating-more-precise-than-double-or-long-double?rq=1

Comment: the fault is it does not give  accrurate enough answer

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. What question do you want us to answer?

Comment: I wanna ask how could I improve the precision of the result of my code

Comment: @witrus `printf("%.15f\n"):` a) this colon should be a semi-colon b) it will always print 0.0 because you forgot to add `, res` after the string pattern. it should be: `printf("%.15f\n", res);`

Comment: I don't understand why this is being blocked / downvoted. Looks like a legitimate question to me. It could be improved by providing an example or examples of the actual and expected input / output, though.

Answer (score 2):

Start the loop with `n` and count down.

The reason is that small numbers around 0 can be added with higher precision because leading zeroes will be represented in the exponent part of the floating point number (hence the name "floating point"), making more of the mantissa available. So you may be able to approach 1 with a more precise sum of the smaller parts.

The loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    res += 1.0 / (2 * i - 1) * (i % 2 == 1 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
}
```

Jsfiddle with a simpler problem to illustrate that ordering may make a difference here:

http://jsfiddle.net/smt56/1

BTW: You should be able to shorten the expression to

```
res += ((i % 2) * 2 - 1) / (2.0 * i - 1)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.It seems to improve precision in this way. But when  n is extremely large like when n equals to 10^7 it still fails to give enough accurate answer.So it still fails in the submission.

Comment: Did you try using long double?

Comment: What about combining terms pairwise, as suggested in the wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80