# What do returning curly braces mean in javascript (ex. return { init : init} )

Tags: javascript

I'm looking over this code:

```
$(function(){
    var $sidescroll = (function() {
        init = function() {
            //STUFF
        };
        return { init : init };    //What does this do?
    })();
    $sidescroll.init();
});
```

What does the return statement mean?  I haven't seen curly braces in a return statement before, and am not even sure what 'init : init'  does.

Comment: Have you tried to play around with the code in the console or a jsfiddle? The best way to learn is to try for yourself.

Comment: [Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: `console.log($sidescroll.init());`, it says the type right in console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Curly braces mean two things in javascript:

1. blocks
2. object literals

You've probably seen the second -- also known in other languages as "dictionaries", key-value pairs, associative arrays, etc:

```
myDict = { a: "apple", b: "banana" };
```

When we say

```
return { a: "apple" };
```

it is the same as saying

```
myDict = { a: "apple" };
return myDict;
```

The "confusing" thing in this case is that (1) the key and the value are identical/have the same character representation, and (2) the value is not a normal string or variable but, a function.  That is, accessing the key "init" of your object/dictionary will give you a function that you can call with `()`.

Answer (score 5):

It returns a new Object instance with the init field set to the value of the init variable. This is called an "Object literal"

I.e.

```
return { init : init };
```

is the same as

```
var o = new Object();
o.init = init;
return o;
```

Comment: ... except much less verbose :-)

Comment: Two upvotes for answering a trivial JS question. Interesting question about floating point precision gets blocked. This is stackoverflow... :-/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509179/how-to-improve-the-precision-of-the-result-due-to-the-lack-of-precision-in-c-d