# Time limit exceeded and the answer was skipped

Tags: double, factorial

This is my code to find factorial inverse

```
double num;
cin>>num;
double i=1,fact=1;
for(i=1;i>0;++i)
{
    fact*=i;
    if(fact==num)
    {
        cout<<i;
        break;
    }}
```

But when i put the factorial of 28 the loop became infinite.
When i output *fact* to check the loop, the answer was output among other factorial numbers but the loop kept going after the right factorial of 28.
It works up to 27! .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by factorial inverse ,provide a sample input and output which you are expecting

Comment: 51090942171709440000 would output 21
as 51090942171709440000 is the factorial of 21,
10888869450418352160768000000 would output 27,
but it won't output 28 when i input 304888344611713801550158626816

Comment: Beacuse the factorial of 28 is out of range of double data type

Comment: But isn't double's range is 1.8e+308, and the factorial of 28 is 3.04888e+29 which is clearly in range?

Comment: Yeah but beyond 20 significant digits double doesn't give exact results

Comment: Look this , It will help : [Double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637621/c-calculating-more-precise-than-double-or-long-double)