# C++ long double

Tags: c++

```
 long double a = 497;
 long double b = 951258;
 long double c = 392673418417;
 v = a * b * c;
```

when I watch the value of v, it is 185646264136289737248, why does this happen? the correct value should be 185646264136289737242.

Comment: check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637621/c-calculating-more-precise-than-double-or-long-double

Comment: 497 is a 9-bit number, 951258 is a 20-bit one and 392673418417 is a 39-bit one. Multiplying them produces a 68-bit number which obviously doesn't fit in your `long double` as it doesn't have that much precision bits

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that doubles can't represent all possible values. If you need that precision and you are only dealing with integers then use `int` or `long long int`.

If you want to know more about it you can google it or read
[this article](https://www.log2base2.com/storage/how-float-values-are-stored-in-memory.html).

Comment: The max value of long long int is only 9223372036854775807 which cannot store the value 185646264136289737242, is there any way we can store the big int value?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c)

Comment: @winston.xie You are not getting extra precision from long double (over a 64 bit int) if it uses 80 bit hardware. Related: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format)